# Next js multiple domain internationalization

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, internationalization, subdomain

I have 3 domains and i have implemented i18n with english, hindi and french
But issue am getting with next js Link
it appends the base url in all Link href and also in next config file basePath:"" like this
if my url is like https://example.com/games
then i use next js Link this make in browser
href= "https://example.com/https://example.com/games"

and if i use only a tag of html this works fine

{m.title}
                    
what should be the issue 
is this with Link or this could be sub-domains 
and my subdomains looks like

https://hi.example.com/
https://fr.example.com/

i have tried like using a tag but this reload my page
this issue comes with Link tag only this attaches link all over the website

Comment: <Link href={`${m.url}`} key={i} prefetch={false}>
                      <a className="">{m.title}</a>
                    </Link>
this is am using for Link next js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.